# Mongodb query: getting join of docs only if satisfies a specific condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to have the mongodb query given these details below, and to have best in performance.

Let me start by an example:

Let me have a collection,

```json
/// the collection

services = 
[
  {
    _id: obj(id1),
    provider_id: "provider1",
    service_code: "code1",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: obj(id2),
    provider_id: "provider1",
    service_code: "code2",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: obj(id3),
    provider_id: "provider1",
    service_code: "code3",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: obj(id4),
    provider_id: "provider2",
    service_code: "code1",
    price: 10
  },
  {
    _id: obj(id5),
    provider_id: "provider2",
    service_code: "code2",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    _id: obj(id6),
    provider_id: "provider3",
    service_code: "code1",
    price: 20
  }
]
```

I want to get all service providers that (only) support these both service codes : code1, code2.

And the total price sorted by total price.

The output is like this:

```json
/// required output based the posted collection and required requirements.

output = 
          
    [ 
      { 
        provider_id: "provider1",
        total_price: 40,
      },

      { 
        provider_id: "provider2",
        total_price: 30,
      }
]
```

I don't want this output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "provider1",
    "total_price": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "provider2",
    "total_price": 30
  },
  {
    "_id": "provider3",
    "total_price": 20
  }
]
```

How to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: I think your collection should be array of objects instead of object of arrays. If it is array of objects then this is possible without aggregation too

Comment: Hi, @AnveegSinha,  What do you mean.. My collection is already an array of objects.

Comment: Can we have more explanation on why id6 record should not be included please?

Comment: Hi @ray I want to return all only the service providers who can do both (code1 , code2).

Comment: I @ray dont want to return the service provider who can only do one or part of my required services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most basic use case of `$group`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      service_code: {
        $in: [
          "code1",
          "code2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$provider_id",
      "service_codes": {
        "$addToSet": "$service_code"
      },
      "total_price": {
        "$sum": "$price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$service_codes",
              [
                "code1",
                "code2"
              ]
            ]
          },
          [
            "code1",
            "code2"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      service_codes: false
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total_price: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ogqQgKljxx4) for your reference.

Comment: Hi @ray, 
Thanks for your answer.. 

I need the output to be as the post. 

```
[
  {
    "_id": "provider1",
    "total_price": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "provider2",
    "total_price": 30
  }
]
```

I need to have (only) the providers who have both ['code1', 'code2]. 

Your solution provided this output: 
```
[
  {
    "_id": "provider1",
    "total_price": 40
  },
  {
    "_id": "provider2",
    "total_price": 30
  },
  {
    "_id": "provider3",
    "total_price": 20
  }
]
```

Comment: @dev313m do not put your expected output in comment. Instead, update your question with the new expected output.

Comment: I've just updated the post. Thanks

Comment: Wow  @ray you are a monster bro. How would be the performance if I had 30k documents inside the collection

Comment: @dev313m 30k is a relatively small amount so it should be fine. The solution is associated with the `$match` at the start to minimize the intermediate result in order to optimize performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tsYDvtD5naD)

This is not like your desired output but it only returns the data which matches with provider_Id.

```
    db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$service"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "service.provider_id": "provider1"
  }
})
```

[$unwind documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)  [$match documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Comment: Thanks Anveeg, I will try to get my output using (unwind)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output you needed using $project:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      service_code: {
        $in: [
          "code1",
          "code2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$provider_id",
      "total_price": {
        "$sum": "$price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "provider_id": "$_id",
      "total_price": 1,
      "_id": 0
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total_price: -1
    }
  }
])
```

I modified rays answer a little bit and just added the project aggregate :) My playground is here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AtQSYo5VV8Q)

Comment: Hi @Xanik ,  this has the same output as ray one